# No respone when using specific slash command, discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm building a private bot with slash commands. Everything works fine, but when I try to use one specific slash command, I get not response. All other slash commands work.

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async(interaction) => {
  if(interaction.isCommand) {
    if(interaction.commandName == 'checkRequirements') {
      console.log("interaction triggered")
    }
  }
})
```

my slash command:

```
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("checkRequirements")
  .setDescription("Überprüft, ob du oder ein bestimmter Spieler die Anforderungen der Gilde erfüllt.")
```

[image]

My application does have application.commands permission.

Comment: Where do you call the [`<Interaction>.reply(..)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) function?

Comment: `interaction.isCommand` is actually a function, not a variable. You have to add the parentheses after it like this => `interaction.isCommand()`

Comment: Thanks, but even with an reply, there is no answer.
@Caladan thanks, but i does not work even with that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the error. An slash command mustn't have capital letters. So to fix the problem I changed the name `checkRequirements` to `checkrequirements`.